# Ignore a /path on a GitHub pages site?

Tags: github, path, hosting, github-pages

I am hosting a static application on GitHub pages. My application structure is like this - I have some front-end facing files, and some Python files that are run periodically to get the data for the front-end, but should not be user-facing:

```
index.html
/js
    index.js
    vendor/
/css
/data
    get_data.py
```

How can I stop everything in `data/` being publicly available on the website?

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 17):

You have two main options:

**Option 1:** Rename your `data` directory to `_data`.

Jekyll ignores files and directories that start with an underscore. You could also create a top-level `_backend` directory and then move your `data` directory into that.

**Option 2:** Configure your Jekyll to exclude the `data` directory.

You can add an `exclude` setting to `_config.yml` to tell Jekyll to ignore your `data` directory.

From [the configuration documentation](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/):

> Exclude
>
> Exclude directories and/or files from the conversion. These exclusions
>   are relative to the site's source directory and cannot be outside the
>   source directory.
>
> exclude: [DIR, FILE, ...]

Googling "jekyll underscore directory" returns a ton of results, including this one which explains all of the above: https://help.github.com/articles/files-that-start-with-an-underscore-are-missing/

Comment: Thanks very much! Does GitHub pages use Jekyll? I wasn't aware of that, would have helped with Googling :)

Comment: @Richard Yep, GitHub Pages uses Jekyll (or at least it **can** use Jekyll). More info [here](https://help.github.com/articles/about-github-pages-and-jekyll/).